no auto import in vscode
I have a problem with vscode and I would appreciate your help. Until yesterday evening my react project using react-router-dom, redux was auto importing but now it doesn't make any suggestions or imports. For example, if I want to use the useNavigate hook, I have to write the import by hand because there is no auto import in any way, or in the same way useSelector or useDispatch or an ordinary  .I would be very grateful if you help me.
For example, if I want to use the useNavigate hook, I have to write the import by hand because there is no auto import in any way, or in the same way useSelector or useDispatch or an ordinary  .I would be very grateful if you help me.

Have you restarted Vscode? Like fully closed it all out and re-opened your project?

Yes, I tried that, I also changed the json setting in the meantime, it is possible that I made a mistake here, but unfortunately I could not fix it.

Check your IntelliSense settings.

alright i‘ll try that
